# MySQL Select ID's which occur on different rows with multiple specific values for a column

Tags: mysql, relational-division

I'm trying to select items from an associative table that have satisfy two or more values of the same field, sounds confusing, let me explain.

```
+-----------------------+
| item_id | category_id |
+-----------------------+
|   1     |    200      |
|   1     |    201      |
|   1     |    202      |
|   2     |    201      |
|   2     |    202      |
|   3     |    202      |
|   3     |    203      |
|   4     |    201      |
|   4     |    207      |
+-----------------------+
```

In the table, I want to be able to select only items which are in the categories that I pass. So for example, if I pass category IDs of 201 and 202, I would want only items that are in BOTH categories (they can have other categories but need to be in at least the categories I'm querying), so in this case, I would want items 1 and 2 only since they are the only ones that are in categories 201 and 202.

My initial SQL statement was something like

```
SELECT * FROM item_category WHERE category_id = 201 AND category_id = 202;
```

But obviously that won't work.

```
SELECT * FROM item_category WHERE category_id = 201 OR category_id = 202;
```

The above query also won't work because it'll return items 4 and 3 as well.

So how would I go about only selecting items that have to at least be in both categories?

Keep in mind that I might be passing more than 2 category IDs.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your expression in a WHERE clause works against a *single row* of the joined result set.  That's why `WHERE category_id = 201 AND category_id = 202` doesn't work -- because it can't be two values on a single row.

So you need some way to join two rows from the table into one row of the result set.  You can do this with a **self-join**:

```
SELECT c1.item_id
FROM item_category AS c1
INNER JOIN item_category AS c2 ON c1.item_id = c2.item_id
WHERE c1.category_id = 201 AND c2.category_id = 202
```

This technique is hard to scale up when you want to search for three, four, five or more values, because it requires *N-1* joins to match *N* values.

So another method is to use GROUP BY:

```
SELECT c.item_id, COUNT(*) AS cat_count
FROM item_category AS c
WHERE c.category_id IN (201,202)
GROUP BY c.item_id
HAVING cat_count = 2
```

Both techniques are okay, and work better in different circumstances.

Comment: Thank you, the second query seems to be more suitable in this case and seems to work fine! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Use either a JOIN, or a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT category_id, fieldhere, anotherfield
FROM item_category
WHERE category_id in (201,202)
GROUP BY category_id
HAVING count(category_id) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each item_id, category_id is unique,

```
select *, count(item_id) as c from item_category
where category_id in (201, 202)
group by item_id
having c = 2;
```

Replace c = 2 with c = (count of categories)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the time to provide the exact query right now, but try something like this:

```
select item_category.* from 
item_category ,  item_category ic1, item_category ic2 where 
ic1.category_id = 201 and 
ic2.category_id = 202 and 
ic1.item_id = ic2.item_id and 
item_category.item_id = ic1.item_id and 
item_category.item_id = ic2.item_id;
```

Maybe conditions are wrong but you can try something this way.

Comment: I'm not sure if ic1.item_id = ic2.item_id  is really needed.

Answer (score -2):

You could try:

```
SELECT * FROM item_category WHERE category_id IN (201, 202, ...)
```

(or, as the comments say... you may not.)

Comment: That will return item_ids 3 and 4