# MySQL - one table, multiple rows with repeated id

Tags: mysql

So I have a "genres" table that has repeated genres and an id, and I want to formulate a query so that I return all the rows that have both genres for a specific id.

For example,

```
+---------+-------+
| genre   | movie |
+---------+-------+
| Musical |   558 |
| Musical |   562 |
| Musical |   597 |
| Musical |   651 |
| Musical |   656 |
| Musical |   791 |
| Musical |   810 |
| Musical |   845 |
| Musical |   859 |
| Musical |   919 |
| Musical |   949 |
| Musical |   971 |
+---------+-------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and

```
+--------+-------+
| genre  | movie |
+--------+-------+
| Comedy |   642 |
| Comedy |   643 |
| Comedy |   644 |
| Comedy |   651 |
| Comedy |   654 |
| Comedy |   658 |
+--------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I would want it to return "movie 651" because it is both in comedy and musical (assuming a query of both 'comedy' and 'musical').

Comment: We seem to be getting this question every day. Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407001/mysql-select-from-associative-table/7407063#7407063 ?

Answer (score 4):

use

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.MOVIE FROM GENRES A, GENRES B WHERE A.MOVIE = B.MOVIE AND A.GENRE = 'Comedy' AND B.GENRE = 'Musical';
```

EDIT - as per comment:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.MOVIE 
FROM
    GENRES A 
  INNER JOIN
    GENRES B
        ON A.MOVIE = B.MOVIE
WHERE A.GENRE = 'Comedy'
  AND B.GENRE = 'Musical';
```

Comment: with slight tweaking SELECT a.movie FROM genres a, genres b WHERE a.movie = b.movie and a.genre = 'Comedy' AND b.genre = 'Musical';

Comment: why the downvote ? if there is something to improve: an explanation would be nice...

Comment: I did not downvote. But you should start using the `JOIN` syntax instead of the (implicit) join with `WHERE`.

Comment: Down vote is because of the old join syntax, if you corrected to 92 syntax, it will be taken off

Comment: @ajreal: why you deleted your answer? It's the alternative way of doing this kind of queries.

Comment: @ajreal just change `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(DISTINCT MOVIE)` to account for what I commented on...

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
    movie
 FROM
    genres
 WHERE
    movie in (SELECT movie from genres where genre = "Musical")
    AND movie in (SELECT movie from genres where genre = "Comedy")
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the list of ids in both

```
select movie from table a join table b on a.movie = b.movie
```