# I want to display the student id, who having all the above 5 units?

Tags: mysql, relational-division

Could u please help me on this my sql query,

```
select STUD_ID,unit_c 
from FCHE_grad 
where (unit_c in("C0001","C0002","ENG300","K0001","K0002")) 
order by STUD_ID
```

the above query returns student_id, who have 4 unit . I want to display the student id, who having all the above 5 units?

Comment: Give us table schema.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Select ID's which occur on different rows with multiple specific values for a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407001/mysql-select-ids-which-occur-on-different-rows-with-multiple-specific-values-fo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `having` cluase to check if the student is in all 5 units

```
select * from FCHE_grad
where stud_id in (select STUD_ID
from FCHE_grad 
where (unit_c in('C0001','C0002','ENG300','K0001','K0002')) 
group by STUD_ID
having count(stud_id)=5);
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c831c/2)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. When i run your query it will return only one entry correct (01821426  ENG300).  But i want to display as 5 entries  like same studentid with above unit_c .             
 
 01821426  C0001
 01821426  C0002
 01821426  ENG300
 01821426  k0001
 01821426  k0002

Comment: @pradeepa: No prob.. Do accept the answer if it helped :)

Comment: Hi G one, I need one more help in the same query. The result can contain 5 modules but these four compulsory ('C0001','C0002'','K0001','K0002').

Answer (score 0):

you should ' ' for varchars in where clause

try this

```
SELECT STUD_ID,unit_c 
FROM FCHE_grad 
WHERE unit_c ='C0001' AND 'C0002' AND 'ENG300' AND 'K0001' AND 'K0002'
ORDER BY STUD_ID
```

Comment: No this won't give the desired result set , see the condition again how a column at a same time can contain all 5 stings ?